# Multiple strings comparison

Tags: python

I have created a calling in restapi to print results in one array, but i need to compare this data before saving this result, example:

```
for id in ids:
    try:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        token, tokenExpireDate = checkTokenExpireDate(apiUrl, client_id, client_secret, token, now, tokenExpireDate) 
        data = getHostDetails(apiUrl, token, id)['resources'][0]
        local_ip = data['local_ip']
        allowed_range_ip = ['10.20.*', '10.10.*', '172.12.*']
        if local_ip in allowed_range_ip:
            print(local_ip)
        else:
            print(local_ip)
    except Exception as e:
        print({'exception': e, 'id': id})
```

I want to compare `allowed_range_ip` with `local_ip`, if `local_ip` is true in `allowed_range_ip` save in array, how i could do this?
I'm new using python, so take easy :)

EDIT:
Example output script (some random ip's), I want to print only ip's similar to `allowed_range_ip`:

```
    10.160.20.02
    172.17.0.9
    10.255.250.68
    10.80.10.20
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried the code that you wrote? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? When you say "compare", what exactly does that mean, and how is it different from what your code does? Can you give some examples of what you expect the `local_ip` values to look like, and explain which should or should not pass the check? It seems like you want to use "wildcards" somehow - am I guessing correctly? Please be explicit.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm editing this post to append script output, answering your question yes, I'm using wildcards to pass a check on local_ip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's builtin [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html) module makes this easy. You create an `ip_network` object, and then you can see if the given `ip_address` is in that network. For instance:

```
from ipaddress import ip_address, ip_network

allowed_range_ip = [
    ip_network("10.20.0.0/16"),
    ip_network("10.10.0.0/16"),
    ip_network("172.12.0.0/16"),
]

local_ip1 = ip_address('10.20.30.40')
print(any(local_ip1 in net for net in allowed_range_ip))

local_ip2 = ip_address('10.21.30.40')
print(any(local_ip2 in net for net in allowed_range_ip))
```